# When the alternator is made to rotate in opposite direction will it effect the electricity generated?

Tags: homework-and-exercises

Suppose that point c (i.e middle of the wheel as shown in the figure) is connected to the alternator.
[image]

for the first one minute the wheel is made to rotate in the direction A(i.e in clockwise direction) with 100 rpm(just assuming) and after one minute the direction of rotation is changed to direction B(i.e anti clockwise direction) but the rpm remains constant. This process of changing the direction is followed every 1 minute.
I have the question that will this any how effect the amount of electricity generated?

Comment: Not clear exactly what you're asking. Are you asking about the electric power that the machine generates? Consider that it would be impossible to _instantaneously_ reverse the direction of the wheel. You are asking it to periodically slow to a complete stop, and then come up to speed again in the opposite direction. That means, it will spend less time running at full speed than if you just let it turn in one direction.

Comment: don't go that deep just stick to the information provided as i have considered a special case. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either sense of rotation of the alternator will produce alternating current with the same magnitude and frequency. What is different is the *phase* of the voltage relative to the position of the alternator shaft at any instant. For opposite rotations, the *phase shift* will be 180 degrees. This means that when you shift rotation directions, the resulting AC waveform-versus-time graph is flipped upside down- peaks become troughs, and vice versa.

Comment: if a device is working for the AC current generated in the above scenario, will the device even work for the 180 degree phase shift generated AC current also.

Comment: certainly. an AC electric motor doesn't care what the phase of the power is.